# Once more => "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server... "

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Screenshot of code

[image]

first of all this is my first post here and I am quite new to programming, so appologies, if I ask stupid questions of my post is missing some info. Just let me know.

I am having the above mentioned failure message when trying to alter a field in an SQL database. I checked a couple of the other posts with similar issues, but they all had different causes and it seems to me my issue has yet another one.
The attached screenshot shows one method that works and one that causes the issue. For the live of me I could not fiugre out what the issue is.

The full failure message is:

```
    Fehlermeldung: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'taskID =79' at line 1
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'taskID =79' at line 1
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3933)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3869)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2675)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1251)
    at databaseConnection.TaskDAOimplDB.updateTask(TaskDAOimplDB.java:110)
    at procedure.Procedure.main(Procedure.java:36)
```

]

[image]

Comment: Add a space to the end of "UPDATE Tasks SET dueDate =" and at the beginning of "WHERE taskID =" in your updateTask statement.

Comment: Also do not build SQL queries using string concatenation.

Comment: Have you tried changing line 110 of TaskDAOimplDB.java to pstmt.executeUpdate()?

Comment: Thanks fror quick reply. I entered the paces. Now the failure message changed to "Unknown column 'March2999' in 'field list" (where March2999 is the value I am handing over as parameter).                   Changing to executeUpdate() did not have any effect from what I could see.

Comment: If your `dueDate` column is a string column, you need to wrap the argument in single quotes. Better yet, use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection hacks and as bonus get easier syntax

Comment: Don't post code contained images, copy your code and paste it your question. Please read this before you ask your next question -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

This is not how [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) should be used. The key is replacement of `?` character in the SQL - this also handles spaced inside of the String which might cause the SQL itslef is invalid otherwise. I also recommend to use [`PreparedStatement::executeUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--). which is more suitable for this kind of query.

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

```
String sql = "UPDATE Tasks SET dueDate=? WHERE taskID=?";

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
    PreparedStatement stm = conn.createStatement(sql);) 
{
    // Don't forget the `parameterIndex` starts with `1` unlike arrays or lists
    stm.setString(1, dueDate);
    stm.setInt(2, taskID);
    stm.executeUpdate();

    System.out.println("Updated");

} catch (SQLException e) {
    ...
}
```